# Detecting vertical drag gesture in vertical scroll view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

for few past days I have been trying to create a vertical scroll view, which has ability to detect vertical drag gesture. (Using SwiftUI)

I have been looking for the right answer but seems to me that many people do have this problem even though no one is able to solve it.

Is there a way for example to create a some kind of overlay which will not interrupt the gestures of the views under the overlay, but be able to detect the gestures itself? I tried .allowsHitTesting(), but it stops to detect any gestures.

Does anyone encountered this problem and figured out?

Thanks

Comment: This might be a good solution: [Observing the content offset of a SwiftUI ScrollView](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/observing-swiftui-scrollview-content-offset/)

Comment: Great article indeed, but I need to detect user drag gesture, or at least tap gesture on the scroll view. I need to detect if user is really holding his finger on the screen while scrolling.

Comment: I've done very little with SwiftUI -- but the impression I get from reading about things like this is that most folks end up using UIKit's `UIScrollView` in `UIViewControllerRepresentable`

Comment: I tried, but incompatible with scrollviewreader

Comment: SwiftUI makes a number of tasks much easier... but there are always trade-offs. From my reading, advanced features / functions provided by `UIScrollView` - and `UITextView` as another example - just can't be done with SwiftUI alone. So... *"how do I replicate `ScrollViewReader` features when using `UIScrollView`"* is another question.

Comment: Would anyone have some idea how to do that? When I was using UIKit, I had problem with the uiscrollview, it was not updating the drag position all the time, just on start of the gesture.

Comment: Maybe if you describe - in detail - what task you're trying to accomplish, there may be an entirely different approach.

Comment: Im trying to detect drag gesture in scroll view. The purpose of this is, when user scrolls over a textfield, the keyboard gets hidden. So Im trying to obtain the drag gesture position, so I know if user scrolls over the text field

Comment: No idea what you mean by *"when user scrolls over a textfield"*? That's why I commented *"Maybe if you describe - **in detail**"*